# Google App Engine Golang returns 404 page not found

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, go

`app.yaml`

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

My `main.go` file:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/cbll/stockmarket-service/lib"
    "net/http"
    "log"
    "google.golang.org/appengine"
)

func main() {
    appengine.Main()
    fmt.Println("Starting the application...")
    // Run application until halted
    for {
        go lib.GetStockData()
        StockController()
    }
}


// Expose controller at http://localhost:8080/
func StockController() {
    var port = ":8080"

    fmt.Println("Starting web server listening on port", port)

    http.HandleFunc("/", lib.StocksHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(port, nil))
}
```

If I comment out the `appengine.Main()`, I can run it locally without any issues. It starts on port `8080`.

`gcloud app deploy` works without issues and will correctly deploy the app to google cloud.

However, `gcloud app browse` which takes me to the site returns `404 page not found`. And indeed, checking the logs with `gcloud app logs read`:

```
2018-01-06 00:04:18 default[20180106t010155]  + exec app
2018-01-06 00:08:32 default[20180106t010155]  "GET /" 404
```

I'm a bit unsure of where to troubleshoot it here. It works locally, and it specifies :8080 as the port as it should(as far as I know?), and imports the appengine main method. What could I be missing?

Edit:

Changing the handlers to

`- url: /`

Results in:

```
2018-01-06 00:17:30 default[20180106t010915]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404
```

.. instead?

Comment: your `script:` in your `app.yaml` should be pointing to `main.go`

Comment: But Google's documentation states: `For Go apps, script should always have a value of _go_app.`? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#handlers_element

Comment: my bad, just checked again. You say that it runs locally just fine without the `appengine.Main()`, does the same happen when uploaded?

Comment: No, if you upload without `appengine.Main()`, you get the error: `parser: found a top level package main with function main, but main does not call appengine.Main();`

Comment: is your app engine using the Flexible Environment? on the appengine github it states it is not compatible with that environment: https://github.com/golang/appengine

Comment: No, I'm using the standard one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard environment provides the main program and runs the http server. Put your initialization code in an init() function. Do not use package main.

```
package app

import (
    "github.com/cbll/stockmarket-service/lib"
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    go lib.GetStockData()
    http.HandleFunc("/", lib.StocksHandler)
}
```

Comment: It now returns JSON! Though, it's empty. `lib.GetStockData()` isn't run? It doesn't log what it should. Though the http server now responds 200, it never runs any of my `fmt.Println` commands.. Strange?

Comment: This answer also worked for me for deploying my app on App Engine - Standard in GCP. After 4 days of playing with these scripts, this was finally the solution that worked (and the only place in the web where this solution apparently exists in relation to App Engine). Thank you very much! +1